# Why is this text not displaying the assigned colors in CSS?

Tags: css

I need to display some text that alternates between one color and another. I've used CSS and `<div style="">` to mark any text that should be a particular color:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                .dark{ color: black }
                .light{ color: blue } 
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="dark">This</div><div style="light">text</div><div style="dark">should</div><div style="light">alternate</div><div style="dark">between</div><div style="light">light</div><div style="dark">and</div><div style="light">dark</div>.
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open this in a Web browser, it only displays text in black. What do I need to fix to make this alternate the colors properly?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is wrong. `dark`/`light` are not styles, they should be classes in this instance.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/z4QaH/)

Your HTML should be..

```
<div class="dark">This</div>
<div class="light">text</div>
<div class="dark">should</div>
<div class="light">alternate</div>
<div class="dark">between</div>
<div class="light">light</div>
<div class="dark">and</div>
<div class="light">dark</div>
```

If you wanted to achieve this via the `style` attribute, you would use the following:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/auuP7/)

```
<div style="color:blue">This</div>
<div style="color:black">text</div>
<div style="color:blue">should</div>
<div style="color:black">alternate</div>
<div style="color:blue">between</div>
<div style="color:black">light</div>
<div style="color:blue">and</div>
<div style="color:black">dark</div>
```

Classes are obviously the better way to achieve this though.

Comment: I changed `<style type="text/css">` to `<class type="text/css">` in the definition, but it did not work.

Comment: @Village If you're using HTML5, just use `<style>`. Look at the jsFiddle examples. I changed `<div style="..">` to `<div class="..">` since dark/light are classes rather than styles.